# How can I generate mysqldump options so it would act like a cusomized export from phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I was wandering if there is a way to generate options for mysqldump so it would act like exporting from phpmyadmin.
For example:
Let's say I have a big database with lots of tables & I want to build a command that exports only the structure of 30 tables, only the data for 40 tables, both data & structure for 50 tables & ignore 60 tables. Also, I want to use UPDATE for dumping data, 'Truncate table before insert', etc...

Is there an easy way to get that using some sort of UI like phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use workbench for this which give options to select table while exporting